Sheets formula - Split letters & Numbers - separate by a hyphen?
I currently have a google sheets spreadsheet that pulls data from another sheet in the same workbook using the below formula in order to format the shift times:
=iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(Data!A1:H99,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="NO SHIFT",x,JOIN(" -"&Char(10),TEXT(SPLIT(x,"-"),"h:mm AM/PM")))))))
As part of the data, I have names & Shift totals in a single cell (this is how the data comes from my other source).
ex:



Name
Times




Firstname Lastname24h/3h
06:00 - 1600


Firstname Lastname22h/3h
06:00 - 1600


Firstname Lastname20h/3h
06:00 - 1600



etc.
I'd like to split the cell containing the name & hourly totals so there is a break (either a hyphen, line break, etc.  so it appears like this:



Name
Times




Firstname Lastname - 24h/3h
06:00 - 1600


Firstname Lastname - 22h/3h
06:00 - 1600


Firstname Lastname - 20h/3h
06:00 - 1600



etc.
Is there a formula that can accomplish this; where / how would I integrate it into my existing formula?
Thank you!
Tried a couple of variations on TEXT(SPLIT(x,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}) but because it target numbers, it affected the shift hours as well.

Which language or environment (Excel, Google-Sheet? ) are you working on? Please tag the right one with the question.

I'm working with google sheets

Assuming the table is in A:B, you can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(A2:A4,"([A-Za-z])(\d)","$1 - $2"),B2:B4})

EDIT
=SORT(MAP(Data!A1:INDEX(Data!H:H,MAX(ROW(Data!A:A)*(Data!A:A<>""))),LAMBDA(x,IF(x="NO SHIFT",x,IF(COLUMN(x)=1,REGEXREPLACE(x,"([a-z])(\d)","$1 - $2"),JOIN(" -"&CHAR(10),TEXT(SPLIT(x,"-"),"h:mm AM/PM")))))),1,TRUE)


This is my current formula to pull in the data, where in the line would I add that code?     =iferror(sort((ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(PackersData!A1:H99,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="NO SHIFT",x,JOIN(" -"&Char(10),TEXT(SPLIT(x,"-"),"h:mm AM/PM"))))))),1,TRUE))

can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can Make an anonymous sample document

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-uY_eMQdQJfJFn0UbnvKSIUyvEnymMp68TpfjxrFzTY/edit#gid=1526924319

Shifts tab is the current setup , Data tab has the info pulled from the external source, DesiredFormat tab has the layout (column A) that I am looking to get to
